# Spring websocket test: repository does not see entity when rollbacked transaction is applied

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-websocket

I've faced with a situation when I was testing websocket endpoint and when I used rollbacked transaction to rollback all changes made during the test I've got an unpredictable behaviour.

I created an simple example to show us what is happenning.

User.java

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    // getters,setters ommitted
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {

    User getUserByName(String name);
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User getUser(String name){
        return userRepository.getUserByName(name);
    }
}
```

Websocket specific

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class Config implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(userHandler(), "/api/user");
    }

    @Bean
    UserHandler userHandler(){
        return new UserHandler();
    }
}
```

UserHandler.java

```
public class UserHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {

        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = session.getHandshakeHeaders();
            List<String> userNameHeader = headers.get("user_name");
            if (userNameHeader == null || userNameHeader.isEmpty()){
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("user header not found"));
                return;
            }

            String userName = userNameHeader.get(0);
            User user = userService.getUser(userName);
            if (user == null){
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("user not found"));
                return;
            }

            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("ok"));

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And eventually UserHandlerTest.java. I use okHttp3 as a websocket test client:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class UserHandlerTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private User testUser;

    private BlockingQueue<String> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        testUser = new User();
        testUser.setName("test");

        userRepository.save(testUser);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatUserExist(){

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user")
                .header("user_name","test")
                .build();

        WebSocket ws = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request,new MsgListener());

        String msg = null;
        try {
            msg = messages.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        Assert.assertNotNull(msg);
        Assert.assertThat(msg,is("ok"));

    }


    private class MsgListener extends WebSocketListener{

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            System.out.println("onOpen:"+response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            System.out.println("onMessage:"+text);
            messages.add(text);
        }
    }

}
```

And my test aplication.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/USERS_TEST
```

All the code above is ok and test is passed. But suppose I don't want to mess the db so I use `@Transactional` on all test methods to rollback all changes after the test is done.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@Transactional
public class UserHandlerTest {
  // the same as above
}
```

And then UserRepository does not find the user saved in setUp test method.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "ok"
but: was "user not found"
```

I tried to reproduce the same situation on the rest endpoint and it works there. Let's see.

UserController.java

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/api/user")
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(String name){
        return userService.getUser(name);
    }

}
```

And UserControllerTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@Transactional
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private User testUser;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

        testUser = new User();
        testUser.setName("test");

        userRepository.save(testUser);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatUserExist() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/user")
               .param("name","test")
        ).andExpect(status().isOk())
         .andExpect(jsonPath("name").value(is("test")));
    }

}
```

Last test is passed and the transaction is rolled back.

I want to see the same behaviour when I test websocket endpoint.

Could someone point me out where the differencies here? And Why Spring does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of [Spring Boot @WebIntegrationTest and TestRestTemplate - Is it possible to rollback test transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698291/spring-boot-webintegrationtest-and-testresttemplate-is-it-possible-to-rollbac/29734845#29734845).

> I want to see the same behaviour when I test websocket endpoint.

You can't. When you declare `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)`, Spring Boot starts an embedded Servlet container.

That's why there are two different transactions if you additionally annotate your tests with `@Transactional`:

1. test-managed
2. spring-managed

For your use case, you will need to stop using `@Transactional` in your test and start manually resetting the state of the database after your test completes. For that I'd recommend the use of `@Sql` with the `AFTER_TEST_METHOD` execution phase. See [How to execute @Sql before a @Before method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126974/how-to-execute-sql-before-a-before-method/27156080#27156080) for an example.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I use @SpringBootTest in both test cases so spring-managed transaction should be made in both cases, should not be?

Comment: No. When you declare `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)`, Spring Boot starts an embedded Servlet container (i.e., a server). This means that you are literally connecting over HTTP when you use `okHttpClient`, and connecting over the network results in a spring-managed transaction on the server that is completely unrelated to the test-managed transaction in your test.

Comment: MockMvc, on the other hand, executes in the same thread as your test, which allows the transactions in your application to participate in the test-managed transaction. That's the key difference.

Comment: Nice explanation. Tnx